# Modular application - dependency as separate module?

Tags: clojure, modules, netbeans

I have a modular application written in Java based on NetBeans Modules (those details probably aren't so important :-) ) and I'd like to add another module written in Clojure language. Clojure programs need to have the clojure library accessible.

Is it generally a good practice to put such a dependency library to another, separate module so it could be shared by multiple modules? Or do you prefer to pack that library into the module?